# How should I handle plagiarized Documentation examples that others have added to?

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism

In responding to flags about users plagiarizing content on Documentation, I've been deleting several of these plagiarized examples. However, I've run into a couple of cases where the original content was plagiarized, but there were subsequent edits that added substantial new content. How should I handle cases like this?

For example, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables/2737/type-casting#t=201607282203494096609) in [its original form](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/7295) was plagiarized from [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Since that original edit, other editors have added attribution for part of the plagiarized wording (but not the code examples) and contributed significant content beyond the original edit.

Should I still delete this example? If it remains, the original plagiarist will continue to gain reputation from their plagiarism. If I delete it, I delete the legitimate contributions of successive editors.

On Stack Overflow, where you have one author, it's easy to make the call on plagiarized content, but I'm not sure how to handle this on Documentation.

Comment: Not a generalizable answer, but the [PHP manual is licensed](http://php.net/manual/en/copyright.php) under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license. The current form attempts to provide attibution, so the subsequent edit arguably was an attempt to conform to the copy-write terms. Whether the source is attributed correctly is a different question, but it looks like it may have been "fixed" by the subsequent edits.

Comment: Yea I think that "plagiarized" is too strong of a term for this. It's more like "temporarily forgot to cite the open source". I think you should just add the proper citation.

Answer (score 32):

The editors didn't know that the work came from a plagiarized source, but I do feel like the example should be removed outright and the chief party responsible for the plagiarism should be taken aside for a bit.

If we build on top of plagiarized work as a starting point, this may do several things:

- Send the message that it's okay to copy wholesale from one site and place it here
- Allow the original poster to receive reputation for their initial, plagiarized work

It's tough to avoid punishing others when it comes to this, since it's so heavily community-oriented, and believe me, they *will* feel punished because they simply didn't realize that someone had lifted documentation wholesale.

But, I do feel like we as editors and contributors should be more vigilant for these things to begin with, and we shouldn't allow anyone to make dishonest gains.

Of course, this raises the question of allowing for a moderator to reverse the reputation gains for a *single* contributor...but I'm not so sure about that one, since the contributors really should be on the lookout for plagiarized content...

Comment: Won't help this situation but maybe should have a "not plagiarized" confirm dialog for first x number of draft submissions by each user. Let people know up front it's not tolerated

Comment: @charlietfl:  Confirmation dialogs can be skipped; warnings can be ignored; messages can be disregarded.  The only realistic thing that can stop plagiarism is if a diamond moderator walks up to 'em with a sharp stick and demands that they cease and desist, lest they use the stick.  It's a problem in Q&A as much as it is here, it's only exacerbated by the fact that it's so *easy* to pull off in Documentation.

Comment: Agreed. To expand a bit further, "removed outright" should mean a hard delete along with any trace that it ever existed.  No saved drafts, no revision history, nothing. Of course, this question is probably better suited for SO's attorneys than the community.

Comment: What if the plagiarized text was edited in, rather than being in the initial revision? Deleting the entire example would provide an avenue for griefing.

Comment: @Comintern: That won't really work, because then, after the next six times they do it, when you say "Hey, stop it", they say "Where's your proof?"

Comment: @JoshCaswell - So wait for a DMCA take-down notice after identifying works that infringe copy-right?  This is a legal issue as much as anything else.  That's why it's probably a better question for SO's attorneys than for its users.

Comment: No, [I definitely agree plagiarized material should be removed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/117558?m=31941693#31941693); I just don't think it's a good idea to degauss the hard drive afterwards.

Comment: @Comintern the DMCA safe harbor provision only protects Stack Exchange as long as they take a hands off approach, so it's best if their attorneys don't get too involved. Far better if we as a community ensure that infringing content is removed as swiftly as reasonably possible

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom:  I don't see how we escape the scenario of editors building on top of plagiarized work.  Perhaps moderators could delete revisions that contained plagiarized work and every work thereafter, leaving the original mostly untouched, but you don't avoid grief in any scenario.

Comment: While I agree that you should not build upon plagiarism, it's also not always evident that it's plagiarized. I do not always do a deep check for plagiarism, but rather take a few phrases which look well-written and feed them into google or so. We sometimes have false negatives and then this happens. In these cases it's mainly part plagiarized, part original content... If the example still makes sense at all without the plagiarized parts, only the problematic parts shall be removed and these who introduced plagiarized content punished/become ineligible for reputation from that edit.

Comment: @bwoebi:  I do agree that it's not always evident that it's there, but in reality, depending on how egregious the plagiarism is, it can be lethal to an entire document.  Figuring out the nuance between what is and what isn't plagiarized is, I will confess, ***bloody difficult*** in an environment like this; however, this won't change the fact that something has indeed been plagiarized.  A copyright holder would be well within their rights to ask for that entire page to be removed, so the argument of preserving what hasn't been wholesale copied becomes moot.

Comment: @bwoebi:  The main issue here is one from moderation, and I'm definitely no moderator, but if I were to put myself in their shoes, the only way I could see reasonably dealing with plagiarized content - even if the work is only partially so - is to remove it outright.  If it's not removed, we only allow others to build on top of it which increases the risk of it being spotted by a copyright holder and asking for its removal, but more importantly, we **reward** this kind of behavior with reputation.  That's what I really want to avoid.

Comment: @Makoto They are in their rights to _ask_ for it. But removal of the plagiarized content itself will also fulfill their claims. I feel like one should rather flag this "foobar has been plagiarized from http://.../..." [a diamond moderator shall then be notified to punish the user eventually]. And then community can have like one or two days time to remove and redo it with original content. In case the plagiarism then still prevails; good then there's maybe no other way than deleting it. But regarding the rewarding problem, I think you should be just punished individually later. Not everyone...

Comment: Not to muddy the waters (but I guess I'm going to muddy the waters anyhow), what about content that's been lifted whole from one source and pasted whole here, but by the original author or with the original author's permission. Should there be a way for the poster to notify the mods/community that this is the case?  IOW, if I "plagiarize" myself (with my permission, of course!) will a moderator hurt me?

Comment: @charlietfl `Confirmation dialogs can be skipped; warnings can be ignored; messages can be disregarded. The only realistic thing that can stop plagiarism is if a diamond moderator walks up to 'em with a sharp stick and demands that they cease and desist` - that's like saying a "no trespassing" sign shouldn't be bothered with, just walk up to the trespassors and threaten to stab them, that's the only way their primitive minds will get the point. I disagree.

Comment: @Viziionary at least letting them know up front helps though, I didn't suggest it would stop it but will warn a lot of them off. Right now there is nothing to indicate it is uncceptable

Comment: could I recommend an amendment to this answer, simply to suggest providing a link to this meta in the comments, if a deletion is performed? There was some issues understanding why I deleted a plagarised example, leading to rejection. I posed the same deletion suggestion with a link to this meta, and it was unanimously accepted within the hour.

Answer (score 8):

*Disclaimer: I made the mistake of not attributing sample code which I had added to Docs, and have gotten a "cease-and-desist" email from a mod.*

**I completely agree that anyone who plagiarizes shouldn't get rep from that edit.**

Completely deleting a topic to eradicate a later edit of plagiarism only happens because there is no other (less destructive) mechanism to properly revert a topic to its pre-plagiarized state.

While plagiarism needs to be dealt with, completely deleting a topic is equivalent to throwing the baby out with the bath water, or killing a fly with a sledgehammer.

**The downside of deleting a plagiarized topic**

1. It also removes prior original content which may have taken previous users a lot of time and effort to contribute.
2. It demoralizes contributors who have done nothing wrong yet are penalized due to another user's (unintentional or deliberate) error.
3. It introduces a means whereby someone can maliciously act to have a valid topic deleted by a moderator, simply by adding plagiarized content to it.

   *While accounts could be banned, the damage has already been done, a vulnerability has been exploited, and it remains to be exploited.*

**How *could* plagiarism be handled by the system?**

Documentation already supports versioning. It just needs a mechanism to allow moderators to rollback to a previous version.

Documentation already supports flagging. Plagiarism should become a specific flag.

1. Allow users to specifically flag a topic for plagiarism.

   This could also automatically "protect" the topic from new edits, to temporarily prevent other contributors from adding additional/valid content to a plagiarized contribution (since their contributions would be discarded).

   There also might be the benefit of treating a plagiarism flag like the spam flag. Once a certain number of flags were reached for a user's contribution, the user's post could automatically be rolled back, sparing a moderator from having to do that.
2. Allow the moderator to rollback a topic back to a pre-plagiarized point in time.

   This would remove both the plagiarized content, as well as the record of the user's contribution. It would specifically stop them from receiving rep, while preserving the work of other contributors up to that point.

**Why do I feel strongly about this?**

A topic that someone else wrote, had needed some improvement. I didn't cite the source of the example which I added to the documentation.

- **Did the topic need improvement?**

  Yes.
- **Did the topic need to be nuked, and all previous contributions lost, because of my error?**

  I think that was an unfortunate consequence of my error, as the topic was otherwise valid and useful. Someone else's efforts are now lost, and the topic would have to be created again from scratch.

Other users' work shouldn't be lost, because of one person's error.

Answer (score 4):

In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/7295), there's an obvious failure to provide [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the first bit. Assuming the rest of the example (particularly the code) is original, it feels like an honest mistake. I remember writing a paper as a student with the encyclopedia in front of me and having to rewrite the thing because it was just too similar to my source. The final product, which is properly referenced, looks not far removed from a good Stack Overflow answer that helpfully quotes another useful resource. As long as folks learn from the experience, I think it's fine to edit into shape and allow the user to keep the reputation in a case like this. (Now if it became a habit, we'd probably need to start down the mod message/suspension route.)

But, for the sake of an answer to your title, let's suppose the rest of the example *is copied* from a third party. I think deleting the entire example is the way to go when the initial draft is lifted in whole from somewhere else. That's a harsh penalty but:

1. It gives a bit of incentive to look for plagiarism before editing.
2. It opens up the topic's example space for a new example covering that ground.
3. It's hard to pull out which contributions haven't been tainted by the plagiarism.

That said, we need more examples to get an idea of how big a problem this might become and consider a range of remedies.

Comment: Let's just say that there was enough outside of this one post to lead me to believe this wasn't an honest mistake. It was also the second example I came across today where plagiarized content had been added to by others. It's a case where the old SO one-post-one-author generalizations no longer apply. Hopefully, it isn't all that common of an occurrence.

Comment: Take this case: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/67239 (scroll down to see diff) … here somebody removed the example entirely where only half of it was plagiarism (initial draft: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/60867 [also: robo-reviewer problem in this special instance] – only the yield explanation+code was plagiarized, the other 50% seem original content). Was it wrong to rollback here and edit? I.e. should I have recreated the example? … If this were an example with a bigger previous history, I'd now get all the credit for it. That's bad too...

Comment: @bwoebi - I should point out that the Asynchronous Programming code and wording was copied from here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php , the Using Icycle example was copied from here: https://icicle.io , and the Remarks section copied from here: https://www.phproundtable.com/episode/asynchronous-php . As a result, deleting all of that seemed justified. It is standard for moderators to delete an entire answer if part of it is plagiarized, for example, as the burden of providing proper attribution lies on the poster, not the community.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree on that (I've found the same sources with simple googling - my bad to not check before editing), especially if it were the initial version only. But it is also annoying if multiple other people made significant contributions to it, then these are remove too. On Q&A, you anyway aren't supposed to make significant edits, thus it's not a problem; but on docs everyone makes edits. … But that wasn't my question… question was whether the rollback was fine or whether I should have recreated it.

Answer (score -2):

One the the primary things that got me to enjoy coding was being able to develop a system to actively sift through data, the web, or a certain site and do something with that information.

I'd be willing to write a bot that constantly copies all original and new documentation in segments, Google's it, and based on open source algorithms to determine plagiarism levels, flag that content for moderator intervention, or maybe even edit it out automatically, and citing the plagiarized source in the reason for editing.

This seems to me like a problem just begging to be solved programmatically. I'll be interested to listen to feedback on this idea before I implement it though.

Alternatively, rather than a server side operation using my account to process the large amounts of documentation (which could be done on a free tier Amazon EC2), we could go the user script route, and supply users with this script which you activate once logged in and the system crawls content, as you watch in your browser and you can quickly scrub your choice of tags for plagiarism while reviewing the content.

The server side route would probably be more efficient, but the client side route would offer greater accountability and oversight for the actions taken by the bot.

Comment: It seems like you haven't actually tried to scrape Google before. As someone with experience doing so, I can tell you there are numerous anti-bot measures in place. Assuming you get past those, it is necessary not to be repeatedly doing searches, otherwise you will get blocked. I've never scraped plagiarism queries, but considering I've gotten CAPTCHAs doing the searches by hand, I think the prospect of automation is bleak (or requires use of a paid API).

Comment: @Laurel I haven't tried to scrape Google, but one of many solutions can work here. To name a few:  Directly crawling a database of programming documentation sites rather than using a search engine. Or a lesser search engine with no anti bot systems. A few other potential solutions, but I'm working on it right now so we'll see what works.