# Plagiarism in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism

SO's [JavaScript Promises Introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/846/introduction#t=201608021921183724564) contains elements that are highly similar to or straight up plagiarized from the [MDN documentation on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  What's the appropriate way to flag this?

## Examples

**MDN**

[image: MDN1]

**SO**

[image: SO1]

---

**MDN**

[image: MDN2]

**SO**

[image: SO2]

---

**MDN**

[image: MDN3]

**SO**

[image: SO3]

The example has 300+ up-votes, and nearly 60 contributors.  Is it just me, or does this suggest that there's a problem with the current peer review method for safeguarding against plagiarism (or lifted elements that have been gently messaged) in SO Documentation?

I had hoped to find an example of good SO Documentation, which is what led me to read this high score example in the first place.

---

**Update**

I removed the copied sections a few hours after Laurel's answer was posted here.  Yesterday I found that the copied sections had been re-added with a [rollback of my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73867), I'm assuming under the notion that the following note added to the bottom of the example is sufficient to cover the plagiarized content:

> Portions of this content are inspired by the contributions of Mozilla
>   Contributors on Mozilla Developer Network's Promise page, licensed
>   under CC-by-SA 2.5.

Since when is "inspired" the same thing as "copied"?  I have once again removed the copied sections.  I left the notice there because most of the other content is indeed inspired by MDN.

Here are the [examples for proper attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution) that MDN recommends.  At a minimum, the attribution, according to their examples, should directly relate to the copied elements.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328896/what-is-currently-being-done-to-keep-plagiarists-at-bay).

Comment: FWIW, the image was originally credited to Mozilla, but [then redrawn](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/65470).

Comment: Documentation really needs a "blame"-equivalent. Nearest I can figure, this was the edit that added the copied Promise wording: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/26271 and this one inserted the diagram: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/50387 . This is an even more complex case than what I asked about here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330016/19679 because there were legitimate edits before and after the copied material was inserted. Looks like these sections will need to be selectively removed, but those who inserted them will still get rep.

Comment: Note that MDN uses the CC-by-SA (they use 2.5) license for their content as well... there should be attribution.

Comment: @Shog9 Really? I mean, yeah, it was "redrawn", but only in the most trivial of senses. **It is still a verbatim copy.** It's still plagiarism if you change a few words of a quotation from a book, and this didn't even go to that much effort.

Comment: My point is that the image *was* credited up to that revision, @Cody. Another twist...

Comment: Does it take more effort to cite it than to flag it? Just add the citation yourself.

Comment: @Hack-R - flagging at least puts moderator eyes on the offenders.  There's also a [balance between original content vs copied content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330467/when-should-i-edit-plagiarism-to-cite-the-source-flag-or-remove?cb=1).  If there is just a small amount of copied content, adding citation seems like the easiest response.  But if you're dealing with a significant amount of copied content, it makes more sense to edit that stuff out and flag the offender(s) (as I learned from Laurel's answer).

Comment: I'm working on a solution to help you help handle this problem. It's a user script which autopilots your browser to communicate between SO and Google, pinpoints plagiarism, and guides you through the process of editing non cited sources or flagging documents in which too much of the content is from other sources. A beta will be ready Soon™ (tomorrow) on meta to test and fine-tune.

Comment: @Hack-R if devlin just supplied the *missing* cite, as you suggest, this would only *encourage* the behaviour at issue here--ie, a user just copies entire blocks from an authoritative source (perhaps changes a word or two), collects the rep (i assume with the assumption that the content is original) and in the event someone does find the original source they copied from, the recommended action is just to is to supply the missing attribution, so the plagiarist gets the rep, never had to personally bother with attribution, yet their contribution (eventually) has a proper citation--win, win, win.

Comment: Am I the only one to see a _Documentation fever_? Easy rep, almost no _serious_ peer review (few downvotes compared to Q&A and broadcasted reputation) and 90% of content is useless. If idea was _decent_ (add examples) it is now going just to repeat what you find elsewhere (and you even get 300/400 upvotes for that!!!) Come on SO's team, I know it's an investment (in money not in knowledge) but if we had quality+usefulness indices they were now under zero...

Comment: Regarding the update, the "inspired by" language does not appear to come even close to CC BY-SA's attribution requirements.  Moreover, even with attribution, the copied text would not be consistent with the official guidance for answers, which says, in part, "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own"  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).  It's not absolutely clear that the same applies to documentation, but I find no reason to think otherwise.

Comment: Q&A addressed an issue, incorrect and inacurate answers to bad questions. A large percentage of documentation appears to be creating incorrect and inacurate documentation when a perfectly legitmate and acurate source already exists.

Comment: Is it considered plagiarism if it is copied from another website but you are still the original author? I find that sometimes I have written answers on Quora that are fitting for Documentation. Is it against the policy to just grab the parts of my answer that are relevant?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is hard to handle, as [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330454/plagiarism-in-documentation#comment377239_330454) said above. It's not as simple as deleting the example.

The best case scenario would have been to catch this before it happened. With the exception of small (for example grammatical) changes, you should always check for plagiarism. There's a lot to find. But that ship has sailed...

The first thing to do would be to remove the content. If the content already exists elsewhere, there is no need to have it here too. Publish your own edits removing all the copied content, with a description stating the material was plagiarized, giving a link to the source. If there was original content that was overwritten, copy and restore it.

You can use the edit history to figure that out. It may take some time, but it should also be possible to track down the users that introduced the content.

You can also leave a mod flag on a question or answer (don't use the documentation "flags", they're not real mod flags). This will preferably be on one of the user's posts, and it should definitely include links to the original source and the copy in documentation. While mods have barely any power in Docs (the only power they have now is needing no peer review), they still have their regular ability to suspend users.

## Please try to find (and reject) this stuff before it gets approved.

This is a message to everyone. If you can't take the time and evaluate the edit properly, don't review at all.

Comment: "But that ship has sailed" what does that mean?  Why not just delete it?

Comment: @JoeBlow I was referring to the fact that it's too late to reject the edit. I also think that outright deletion is a bit unfair to those who contributed honest content, especially before the plagiarism happened.

Comment: okie dokey.  but really, the issue seems very simple: (1) click "edit".  (2) the plagarised part.  highlight, then click "delete".  (who cares who or which edit inserted the plagarized part?)  No big deal, but I'm not sure what I'm missing here. the solution is **"Click edit, and delete the plagarized part."**.  It does nothing for SO's future stock price if "the documentation stuff is just copied".

Comment: @JoeBlow *Publish your own edits removing all the copied content*. You're missing the fact that I already said that, just with different words. (Documentation works differently than Q&A, so the wording is purposefully different.)

Comment: fair enough.  Rock on.

Comment: I removed the plagiarized content yesterday and [it was added back](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73867).  Is the note stating portions were "inspired" by MDN sufficient?  Inspired is not the same thing has Copied.

Comment: @devlincarnate [Harvard](http://usingsources.fas.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k70847&pageid=icb.page342054) calls that "inadequate paraphrasing" and it is only one breed of plagiarism. In any case, it fails to be [proper attribution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) by our standards, so it is NOT enough. Ugh, is Docs really teaching me more about plagiarism than programming?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Docs to *augment* the official documentation in cases where it is insufficient? So, if significant sections are copy&pasted from official docs, that seems to indicate that the official docs *are* good enough and the topic should not be on Docs in the first place?

Comment: @JörgWMittag The copy-pasted sections should not exist as you said. However, it may help to hear things explained another way, even when the official docs are very good.

Comment: How is not proper attribution? According to [*MDN's* attribution rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Copyrights_and_licenses), which is actually what matters in this case (since it's their content), it is adequate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - shouldn't the attribution state that the material is **from** MDN, not **inspired** ?  And the attribution should occur under each copied element, as [described in the examples for attribution]  (https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution) recommended by MDN

Comment: @devlincarnate I could have said it is a "derivative work" if the word "inspired" is causing heartache, I figured that was implied. Also note on that same page the header *Don't make it too complicated* and the text *There is no one right way; just make sure your attribution is reasonable and suited to the medium you're working with.*

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I think that's where the disagreement is occurring.  There's nothing complicated about putting that notice under each copied element, and making it specific to the copied element.  And, in fact, there's no need for "derivative work" or "inspired".  Just site the source.

Comment: @devlincarnate I did cite the source. There is no single piece of directly copied content in the final draft, except a portion of a sentence. The changes to the image make it a derived work, as do the wording changes in the three bullet points. Ironically, this is all content licensed under Creative Commons, a set of rules which was specifically made so that content could be shared easily...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - this is my last comment on the matter: Did you read the examples in the link I posted on best practices for attribution under Creative Commons?  It identifies the specific derivative work and the specific source.  Also, they make a distinction between slight modification and derivative work.  None of the examples we're talking about are derivative. They are slight modifications, **at best**.  What I don't understand is why you want some blanket, non-specific attribution which doesn't distinguish original content from copied content.

Comment: _"This is a message to everyone. If you can't take the time and evaluate the edit properly, don't review at all."_ Heh, you must be new to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Sorry to break the comment chain, but there is one thing I didn't really understand in this answer: where exactly are we supposed to leave **real** mod flags? On a post of the offender in Q&A?

Comment: +1 that it's better to catch these before they are approved, -1 because that's a little difficult ***when it only takes one person to approve an edit***.