# Suggestions on how to Combat Plagiarism in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism

I have spent the last 48 hours going over the Documentation (for the SQL topic primarily) and have noticed a large volume of plagiarized code.

It seems people are just ripping off the MSDN technical documentation and changing field names. I saw a couple that even had *AdventureWorks*.

I guess there are a couple of questions.

1. What do people find to be the best method of managing plagiarism?
2. Should we possibly increase the rep limit for users who can Contribute / Approve?
3. How can greater onus be placed on reviewers to ensure that code plagiarism doesn't occur?
4. In some instances code will appear plagiarized when it's not (basic best practices resulting in similar code); how do you determine that it is legitimate?

Comment: First offence should be a warning. Multiple offences should result in a (temporary) contribution ban, kind of like how review queue bans work.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330016/215552 or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330454/215552

Comment: Plagiarism is one thing, but creating an example using a widely available and known sample database is something else.  Not saying that example *isn't* plagiarism, but be careful of assuming so just because they're using Adventureworks Cycles or Contoso as an example company...

Comment: Suspensions. Lots and lots of suspensions.

Comment: See here as well for pointers from Jon Ericson on what to do if it's already approved: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330016/how-should-i-handle-plagiarized-documentation-examples-that-others-have-added-to/330031#330031

Comment: I think we are tackling the wrong problem. What motivates these users to plagiarize in first place? Lets start with that.

Answer (score 23):

I have a bit of experience with fighting plagiarism in Docs. I've actually proposed that [getting caught should have consequences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330001/6083675). In other words, the people who plagiarize should be locked out of contributing early, before they contribute a lot.

The way I generally catch plagiarism is by searching for phrases in quotes on Google. If it's something really basic, then you're going to find lots of different instances in the search results. I do this before approving anything more than a grammatical or formatting fix.

Of course, this does not work very well for finding copied code. (SQL doesn't have too much of a problem here, due to the design of the language.) Either way, I'd like to recommend this [really cool trick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675), which is useful all around; you can use the `code:` operator to help find code on Stack Overflow (or another SE site), even with symbols.

I also like Copyscape's tools (except for reaching the maximum and being rate limited, since I'm using the free versions):

- [Plagiarism finder](http://www.copyscape.com/)
- [Diff checker](http://www.copyscape.com/compare.php)

Of course, this advice is specifically geared towards catching plagiarism before it's approved and added. I've already written about cleaning up after plagiarism [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330464/6083675).

Comment: Your link appears to be what us programmers call a "diff" tool. :-) There are hundreds of them online. And apparently, unless you pay for Copyscape Premium, it doesn't provide any way to determine *if* something has been plagiarized. The ubiquitous Google is a fantastic resource for that. Pick a phrase that looks distinct (*i.e.*, not something ridiculously common), enter it into Google in quotation marks, and check the surrounding sentences. Usually a quick check is sufficient. Most plagiarists are not sophisticated enough to attempt to cover their work.

Comment: @CodyGray Most plagiarists aren't contributing to a crowd-sourced project where contributions are fluid and changing. It's mostly useful when you know there is plagiarism, but it is obscured by edits.