# Policy about plagiarized documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

[@Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320693/jason) wants to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/78390) [REST introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rest/1664/introduction-to-rest/6532/rest-overview#t=201608250738295538706) to *removed plagiarized content*. It's right that the main part of the example is largely inspired/copied from [RRM](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). What is the policy for SO Documentation? Shall we approve Jason's update or shall we reject it, e.g. in case of the source becomes unavailable?

Comment: Other related posts: [How should I handle plagiarized Documentation examples that others have added to?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330016/247702) and [When should I edit plagiarism to cite the source, flag, or remove?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330467/247702)