# How to improve documentation (and copy pasting official docs)

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

My curiosity made me visit [the link to the documentation pages for Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/doctrine2/1064/getting-started-with-doctrine2) which was shown in the side bar when going through posts tagged with `Doctrine2`.

[image]

In the first installation and setup example it is suggested to use composer to install Doctrine 2:

> Doctrine 2 is easy to install via composer
>
> ```
> composer require doctrine/orm
> ```

But Doctrine 2 is much much more then just an ORM (Object Relational Mapper), [it also comes with an ODM (Object Document Mapper)](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) which is installed with composer like this:

> ```
> composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm
> ```

And in case of using for example Zend-Framework you need to install [the doctrine ORM module for ZF2](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule):

> ```
> composer require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module
> ```

So either OP should add all the examples or mention that this specific example is only for ORM and Symfony framework (and possibly other frameworks).

It seems to me that OP didn't put much effort in his post, it is more or less a direct copy from the [Doctrine 2 ORM installation chapter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#installation-and-configuration) in the official documentation or [this documentation page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2015/12/25/orm-2-5-3.html) and as such it doesn't add much value compared to the existing official Doctrine 2 documentation.

**Questions specific to this post:**

- If this would be a question I would leave a comment, but this isn't possible in the Documentation pages. So what is the best way to deal with this? Is it legitimate to downvote this documentation?
- Say I would like to improve this documentation, should I add all examples for the frameworks, or should I rather remove the installation example and make the documentation post more abstract and refer to the installation manual in the official documentation that is actually quite good.

**A more general question:**

- I can see a use for documentation when there isn't any official documentation available. But is duplicating (copy pasting) official documentation to the StackOverflow Documentation pages considered good practice? Is it in the interest of anybody if well documented modules are simply duplicated? There is a big chance that documentation on StackOverflow will get outdated while the official documentation is kept up-to-date. It could be better to simply refer to those official documents instead. Would that be considered good practice?

Comment: There is a lot of copy-pasting going on in Documentation. If you see outright copy-pastes, you need to find the copy-paster and flag one of their posts. You probably should **not** flag the Documentation item; last time I tried that, it turned out that "custom mod flags" in Documentation turned into Improvement Requests, for all the world to see.

Comment: "It could be better to simply refer to those official documents instead. Would that be considered good practice?" I would definitely regard this as good practice. Documentation is not supposed to replace good existing documentation, rather complement it with examples.

Comment: *"it turned out that "custom mod flags" in Documentation turned into Improvement Requests, for all the world to see."* That does not sound like a good idea, why do we do that?

Comment: "Is it legitimate to downvote this documentation?" **Of course it is!** That's exactly what downvotes are for - to indicate that a post is technically inaccurate or has other problems!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330016/how-should-i-handle-plagiarized-documentation-examples-that-others-have-added-to   If the original version of an example was a straight up copy/paste from official docs, just delete the example, see this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330031/4409409

Answer (score 4):

> If this would be a question I would leave a comment, but this isn't possible in the Documentation pages. So what is the best way to deal with this?

If you don't have time to actually add that information in, then you should leave an improvement request. If you downvote it, you'll get a menu suggesting possible improvement requests to leave. Those requests include user-provided text (comment-sized) to explain what needs to be added.

> Say I would like to improve this documentation, should I add all examples for the frameworks, or should I rather remove the installation example and make the documentation post more abstract and refer to the installation manual in the official documentation that is actually quite good.

Well, that's really the question. Supposedly, Docs.SO was created to handle documentation that didn't exist, yet it doesn't really do a good job at that. We certainly don't want a raw copy&paste of other documentation.

And whether such alternate installation instructions should be added as examples or to the same examples is likewise unresolved. Examples are supposed to be at least nominally independent of one another (yes, this is at odds with the fact that you edit whole topics, not examples. But I didn't design this thing). So if installing one part of this package can be used without the others, then it makes sense for them to be separate examples.

So basically, play it by ear. We're defining the rules as we go, presumably based on what works.